# What to call a certain shape of lips

Tags: vocabulary

What to call lips which are fleshy (full) and stick out a little bit? I am not sure if 'stick out' is appropriate or not. 
I mean, the lips making someone with them look sulky (but actually he or she is not).

I searched the Internet and it says that such lips are called 'fish lips' or 'prominent lips'.

Comment: **POUT**: push one's lips or one's bottom lip forward as an expression of petulant annoyance or in order to make oneself look sexually attractive.

Comment: 'pout' is deliberately done act. It is not natural. So, calling a girl with 'pouted' lips may mean that **she does it** whereas the OP seems to ask for a *natural* or better say physiological structure of a girl having that type of lips. @JoeDark

Comment: @MaulikV There is such a thing as a natural pout but having no experience with the opposite sex, you can be forgiven for not knowing.

Comment: But then you need to add **natural** to that! @JoeDark. And you are right...have never seen a girl with 'naturally pouted' lips. In almost all cases, she *does* that gesture!

Comment: @MaulikV - At least in AmE, it's usually said as _pouty lips_, not _pouted lips_, and, in some societies, it's [all](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Pouty-Lips) [the](http://blog.candylipz.com/what-are-pouty-lips/) [rage](http://www.how2girl.com/how-2-get-fuller-pouty-lips-move-over-angelina-jolie/) (that's three different links for the curious, and there's even an entry in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pouty)). **Disclaimer**: I'm posting these links for the betterment of English understanding, not as modeling advice. I personally find this look quite silly.

Comment: @J.R. I have *no* problem with *pouty*; what I said was about 'pouted'.

Answer (score 4):

**Fish-lips** is derogatory.

(Slightly) **protruding** lips is objective.

**Pouty** lips is descriptive.

See [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pouty%20lips%2Cprotruding%20lips%2Cfish%20lips&year_start=1920&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpouty%20lips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprotruding%20lips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfish%20lips%3B%2Cc0) for contexts.

Comment: Pouty lips are quite attractive and very popular in Hollywood. Incidentally, the first four actors and actresses came to my mind when reading the question are also on this list: http://blog.candylipz.com/20-beautiful-lips-time/.

Comment: Someone who's had cosmetic surgery to give themselves pouty lips, but gone a bit too far, is said to have a 'trout pout'.  But that's not a polite thing to say to someone.

Comment: All of those are pretty good, but I wonder why nobody has just suggested "full lips", [which is way more common than anything else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pouty+lips%2Cprotruding+lips%2Cfish+lips%2Cfull+lips&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpouty%20lips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprotruding%20lips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfish%20lips%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20lips%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: **full lips** <> the OP's "look...sulky".

Comment: Just my take: I think _fish lips_ is sometimes used mockingly when someone is trying way too hard to look flirtatious in a selfie, though you might be hard pressed to find such usages in an ngram. I think the term has gained traction along with the recent boom in Facebook selfies.

Answer (score 1):

In women's fashion/cosmetology that look is called **bee stung lips**.  Sometimes hyphenated **bee-stung**.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bee-stung

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bee-stung+lips

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-Bee-Stung-Lips

Answer (score 1):

You can describe them as luscious, or voluptuous, or succulent if you are trying to get that sense of sexiness across. However, if your intention was to simply describe them, then maybe "full" is enough -- but then again lips can be full without being pouty...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ['fish lips'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fish%20lips) seems to be the word. But I'm *not* sure whether it's polite to say that.

If you are talking about lips those are a bit *large* and seems to  be *out of their original space*, you may call them 'protruded'.

> She has protruding lips

However, it's my personal opinion. Being a healthcare provider, I have used 'protruding eyes' to refer to eyes coming a *bit out* of their frame. The same way, we can use this for other body organs. Say 'protruding ribs/knees' etc. So, 'protruding lips' ***may*** work.

Answer (score 0):

For a facial expression, I think what you might want here is [Duck Face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_face).  The image on the Wikipedia page is not the best, so also check out the [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=duck+face&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

True, this is basically just a person making pouty lips, but "Duck Face" is the in-word right now brought on by all the selfies of girls making this face while trying to "look hot".  At this point some people do it as a joke.

If you're just talking about someone having larger-than-normal lips, "full lips" works, and ["voluptuous"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voluptuous) is a common adjective for full lips.

Comment: Another common term is [voliminous lips](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=voluminous+lips&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).